# in ATK4, How do i amend a model to get a DISTINCT list

Tags: php, frameworks, model, distinct, atk4

I have a list of stories defined and, in another table,  a set of tasks attached to those stories.

For a given user, i want to get a distinct list of story numbers e.g. if the user has multiple tasks, the story will only be listed once.

I can do it with a direct SQL but how should i implement this with a model in ATK4 ?

At the moment, the table linking members to stories has a model defined like this

```
<?php
 class Model_StoryMember extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='vscrum_story_member';
public $table_alias='sm';

function init(){
           parent::init();
           $this->addField('story_id')->system(true)->visible(false)->   
             defaultValue($this->api->recall('story_id'));
           $this->addField('team_id')->system(true)->visible(false)->
             defaultValue($this->api->recall('team_id'));
           $this->addField('sprint_id')->system(true)->visible(false)->
             defaultValue($this->api->recall('sprint_id'));
           $this->addField('member_id')->refModel('Model_Member');
           $this->addField('points')->datatype('numeric');
           $this->addField('notes')->datatype('text');
 }
 }
```

This model could contain a record for each user e.g.

```
    STORY
    ID     Name     Points Responsible
    1000   Story 1      2     1
    1001   Story 2      3     1

    STORY_MEMBER
    ID     Story    Member  Points Description
    1      1000     1       .5     Task 1
    2      1000     1       .5     Task 2 
    2      1000     2       1      Task 1
    3      1001     1       1      Task 1
    4      1001     2       1      Task 2 
    5      1001     3       1      Task 3
```

so if i view the data for user 1 or user 2, i only want two lines returned (even though user one has two tasks in story 1000)
story 1000
story 1001

and for user 3, i would only get one row for 
story 1001.

To add further, i want to be able to union two queries and return the distinct list so if i query it for member 1, 
if i have a basic sql  e.g.

```
SELECT id, name
  from story
 where responsible=1
 union
select s.id, s.name 
  from story s, story_member sm
 where s.id=sm.story_id
   and sm.member_id=1
```

i will get a list of the stories which member one is responsible for and also those for which they are involved.  The union takes care of the sort unique so each story is only returned once (as it's very likely they are involved in the stories they own) but there may also be stories they are involved in but someone else is responsible for.

Is there a way to union the two queries together so i get one array returned in the page ?

TIA

Comment: You can try overriding dsql() and changing the request on the fly.

Comment: Is there no way to specify it in the model ?- if not then i can just put a sql directly in the page and populate the data i wanted but wanted to check if there was a way i could add to the chain where i addConditions to the model. No worries - still trying to identify the boundaries in the framework and what it does do, is already more than i expected. thanks

Comment: yeah, i wouldn't mess with model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using query manually. Try:

```
$dsql->option('distinct');
```

You can change the query of your view, for example if you have a grid, then:

```
$this->grid->dq->option('distinct');
```

Call this AFTER the model has been set.

Comment: And if i have several queries unioned together, is there a way to get a single array back from the query ?  E.g.  "SELECT id, name, xxx from  stories_planned UNION select id, name, xxx from stories_involved" and then apply option distinct on top ?

Comment: Oracle spoils people! :) $myquery = $dsql->select().' UNION '.$dsql2->select();  

$this->api->db->getAllHash($myquery);

Comment: :) I'm thinking maybe to let mysql do the work which means i just create a view of the queries and create a new model based on the view with addConditions in the page for the member_id.  Keeps the code clean and simple, uses MVC and should work fine. Thanks

Comment: ok. I've always tried to simplify mysql to make it possible to go into nosql or cache data easier, but your approach makes sense too.